# UITableViewCell height auto layout not working on iOS 10

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a very simple `UITableViewController`, where I want to set a text on each `textLabel` of the `UITableViewCell`s.

The height should be calculated by autolayout. Therefore, in my `viewDidLoad` set following values to the `tableView` properties:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

This is my `cellForRow` method, where I initialize the default `UITableViewCell` and set the text to its label.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.text = "hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello"
        return cell
    }
```

My problem is, that the cell won't grow according to the size of the label. This issue only appears on iOS 10. On iOS 11 everything gets layed out as it should.

Please check following screenshots:

- **iOS 10**

[image]

- **iOS 11**

[image]

**EDIT: 24th of May 2018**

Having the `textLabel` only, it will work if there is an actual value on `estimatedRowHeight`.

But having a cell with style `.subtitle`, and setting a value to the `descriptionLabel`, the layouting won't work. Same issue: iOS 10 does not work. iOS 11 works (cell resizes according to both labels).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This configuration from your `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

...works only on iOS 11. It is an iOS 11 innovation and does not apply to earlier systems.

For iOS 10, you must supply an actual `estimatedRowHeight` value (such as `60`) to turn on automatic variable row height calculation.

Comment: This fixed the issue. But not if the cell uses the `descriptionLabel` too, it won't work on iOS 10. I updated my questions accordingly.

Comment: @kchromik The simplest solution is: don't use the built-in `.subtitle` style. It is not intended for self-sizing cells, and so it doesn't work in a backwards compatible way. Just make a custom cell type with two labels. That will work on both iOS 10 and iOS 11.

Comment: good to know, I thought it will work out of the box. Will build my own cell then, thanks for you help.

Comment: Variable height fixed issue in iOS10. You saved my day. Thank you very much.

Comment: This helped. I have been struggling for nearly 16 hrs and no clue how to resolve this. Weird and don't understand why this is an issue in iOS 10 in first hand.